# OSX Can ping and GUI login but Unable to SSH login via LAN

Tags: ssh, lan, osx-leopard, remote-login

I am **unable** to ssh via LAN using hosts admin credentials.

I am able to login to a system using admin credentials via the Mac's GUI

I am able to ping the Mac via LAN

Sharing > Remote Login is enabled for the admin user and all options permitted.

At the Terminal prompt I would usually expect to see the following after making the request:

> The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be
>   established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx. Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)

But this does not happen and the Terminal just waits for me to break the command.

I am able to ssh to all the other systems on the LAN but not this one.

What else could I be missing ?

Comment: Pass `ssh` the `-v` flag so you can see how far it gets and what it's waiting for.

Comment: @David Schwartz I get this : `OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: Okay, so it can't reach the other machine on port 22 (the SSH port). That usually indicates a firewall issue. (On either machine.)

Comment: @David Schwartz Thanks for the pointer. So I went to the host Security > Firewall and changed it from "Allow only essential Services" to "Allow all incoming connections". This worked. But I don't want the system completely open, so I tried "Set access for specific services and applications" and this also worked. However, I would be keen to learn what OSX will actually allow and not allow if set to "Allow all incoming connections" which appears to be the default setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments now show, the firewall was blocking incoming connections on port 22.

Setting the firewall to "allow all incoming connections" will do just that, no inbound TCP connections will be blocked.